# Como enviar o input da PartialView para um controller?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor, partialview

Tentei encontrar algo que me tirasse esta dúvida, mas não há nada em concreto para o que eu quero.

Estou a usar o Visual Studio 2015 e MVC 5 e Razor no meu projeto.

Tenho um formulário (Create) com um submit numa partial view e tenho essa partial view renderizada numa outra view (é uma caixa para comentários num post).

Tenho também implementado o **[HttpPost]** do Create() mas quando clico em **submit** para submeter o comentário ele não faz o Post para a minha função **[HttpPost]**, como faço para mandar os dados para esse método? Tenho o parâmetro de entrada assim: Create (FormCollection collection).

Eu sei que essa pergunta pode parece trivial, mas estou ainda numa face muito inicial.

Código da Partial view:

```
@model shanuMVCUserRoles.CommentSet

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Adicione um comentário</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MemberID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new {    @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Criar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

E controller:

```
    // GET: Comment/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        CommentSet newComment = new CommentSet();

        return PartialView(newComment);
    }

    // POST: Comment/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        CommentSet newComment = new CommentSet();

        BlogEntities db = new BlogEntities();

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(collection["MemberID"]);

        newComment.Content = collection["Content"];
        newComment.MemberID = Convert.ToInt32(collection["MemberID"]);
        newComment.MemberSet = db.MemberSet.Single(m => m.ID == id);
        newComment.PostID = Convert.ToInt32(collection["PostID"]);
        newComment.VotesDown = 0;
        newComment.VotesUp = 0;



        try
        {
            db.CommentSet.Add(newComment);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index"); /*AINDA NAO CONFIGUREI ISTO*/
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Código onde chamo a partialview:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
            <h5>@item.Content</h5>
            <div class="list-group">
                @foreach (var comment in item.CommentSet)
                {
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@comment.MemberSet.UserName</h4>
                        <p class="list-group-item-text">@comment.Content</p>
                    </a>
                }

                @Html.Partial("_AdicionarComentario", new CommentSet { PostID = item.ID })

            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Se possível, poste o seu código para analisarmos melhor seu problema

Comment: Uma coisa que observei agora, você tem a propriedade `PostID`, porém não existe um `input` com o valor dessa propriedade na tua PartialView, adiciona um `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostID)`

Comment: Já corrigi. Estive pesquisando e vi pessoal que usa Ajax para fazer algo parecido, será bom para este caso? (não queria aprender tudo de uma vez, por isso é que prefiro usar so c# e razor, mas se for preciso...)

Comment: Acredito que não precise usar Ajax.
Tenta especificar a action no seu Form, ficando algo do tipo `@using (Html.BeginForm("TuaAction", "TeuController"))`

Comment: Isso resolveu o meu problema. acho que devia colocar isso nas respostas, pareceu magia haha

Comment: Como você sabe que nao está chamando o metodo Create?
Colocou um breakpoint na função e a execução não passou por ela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução para seu problema é especificar no seu Form a action, ficando da seguinte forma `@using (Html.BeginForm("TuaAction", "TeuController"))`

Porém por você utilizar View tipada, você pode alterar o seu `Create(FormCollection collection)` para `Create(CommentSet commentSet)`.

Ficando da seguinte forma

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CommentSet commentSet)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.CommentSet.Add(commentSet);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(commentSet);
        }
```

Mas o seu principal problema é que o `Create` falta o atributo `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, tendo esse atributo o objetivo de proteger o acesso a sua aplicação por pedidos Http falsificados, ele garante que o pedido venha somente da sua View usando uma espécie de "chave".

Comment: mas que diferença faz ter o CollectionForm ou CommentSet? Eu não consigo sequer chegar ao método [HttpPost]

Comment: Completei a resposta.

Comment: Continuo sem conseguir enviar o comentário para a base de dados. Um detalhe que pode ser útil: depois de fazer submit a página recarrega, mas se eu atualizar a página (F5) recebo isto: "Para mostrar esta página, o Firefox tem de reenviar informação que repete ações realizadas anteriormente (como uma pesquisa ou confirmação de uma encomenda)."

Comment: Coloca o código da view onde você carrega essa partial.